# PostgreSQL "pass-through" aggregate function that uses other aggregate functions

Tags: postgresql, postgis

Is there a way to create a PostgreSQL aggregate function that can call other aggregate functions, handle exceptions, and return a single value?

This query takes a set of geometries, merges them together, tests if a constant geometry is fully within the merged result, and returns true false.  The problem is that often merging will raise an exception for various reasons, so I need to do a fallback, i.e. an `iferror()` excel-style function that will execute another operation like `st_union()` instead of `st_collect()`. If that also fails, ideally I should iterate over all geometries individually to see if any one of them matches my test.

```
SELECT ST_WITHIN(
               ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((0 4096,0 0,4096 0,4096 4096,0 4096))', 3857),
               ST_COLLECT(geomtry)
           ) AS IsEmpty
FROM (select geomtry from ...) AS src;
```

Pseudo code:

```
FUNCTION test_is_empty(geometries: SET<geometry>)
  TRY:
    RETURN ST_WITHIN(
               ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((0 4096,0 0,4096 0,4096 4096,0 4096))', 3857),
               ST_COLLECT(geometries));
  EXCEPT:
    TRY:
      RETURN ST_WITHIN(
                 ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((0 4096,0 0,4096 0,4096 4096,0 4096))', 3857),
                 ST_UNION(geometries));
    EXCEPT:
      TRY:
        RETURN SELECT MAX(ST_WITHIN(
                   ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((0 4096,0 0,4096 0,4096 4096,0 4096))', 3857),
                   individual_value))
               FROM geometries;
      EXCEPT:
        RETURN FALSE;
END
```

Comment: Yes, [you can define your own aggregates](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xaggr.html). However, calling other aggregate functions is not that easy, as you would need to actually call their internals. A workaround would be to collect all the rows in an array and then run your custom function (quite like you did define it) as a `finalfunc`. Not sure about performance of that approach though, you might not want to run that on large groups.

Comment: Why do you need a new aggregate function? Just implement your pseudo-code.

Comment: Thanks @Bergi, I was worried about the perf too, and it seems calling internals of another func might be a path forward (not desirable, but seems to be unavoidable).  @ Laurenz Albe my concern was exactly as Bergi mentioned - dealing with an aggregates as parameters.